# how to use textfied and button to get results from an if else statement

Tags: java, netbeans

how to use if else statement using textfield as an input then use a button to show results, I have tried using the code the bellow ,but it does not allow me to use " if else " condition for second condition , below is my code;

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());

if  (x>=120&x<200)
         {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "select drum : PPJ upwards")};

if else (x>=230&x<=300);
     {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"select drum :RRf Upwards");}
else
     {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"incorrect entry");}
}
}
```

Comment: _"I have tryed using the code the bellow"_ - ummm, _what_ code?

Comment: Also, what language. I'll assume it's Java because of the netbeans tag, but I may be wrong. Please tag your questions correctly. If it is Java, use the java tag. It is is a Swing app, add the Swing tag

Comment: And where is your code you are talking about?

Comment: The code you have provided has serious formatting issues as well as serious syntax error such as incorrect use of parentheses and semicolons. this code won't even be compile correctly.

Comment: show me an example of a correct code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to write `if else` condition is as below

```
if (condition1 && condition2) {

} else if (condition3 && condition4) {

} else {

}
```

And if my assumtions are correct below s how your code should be written as following;

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText().toString()); // getText needs to be converted to String before parsing it to int.

if (x>=120 && x<200) { //in the if condition you need two && not one &
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "select drum : PPJ upwards");//semicolon should be here 
}//putting semicolon here is wrong

else if (x>=230 && x<=300)//putting semicolon here is also wrong
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"select drum :RRf Upwards");
}
else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"incorrect entry");
 }
```